# how to get number of the day from date?

Tags: php, date, formula

how to get number of the day from a date in php? 
for example: the date format is given: **4/23/2012** and it outputs **1** or **monday** or **mon**...

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$date = '2007/08/30'; 
$weekday = date('l', strtotime($date)); // note: first arg to date() is lower-case L
```

Comment: How to output the day number, instead of date name ? like monday =  1

Comment: @AgengD.Prastyawan I know this is super old but looks like its still showing up in search results. For anyone else wanting to know how to get the integer representation of the day of the week, starting at 0 for index, to achieve a 1 for monday: ```$weekday = date('w', strtotime($date));```

Answer (score 10):

Try something like:

```
<?php

$rawDate = '4/23/2012';

echo date('N', strtotime($rawDate));
?>
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/jICqh

Checkout [PHP's `date()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) documentation for more ways to format dates.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date("l", mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 23, 2012));
```

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the number you want, the number of the day of the current month or the day of the actual year. See the [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for details.